# Hook is not invoked

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a function I want to execute when a user finishes a quiz.

```
function wilson_random_task_quiz_finished($quiz, $score, $session_data) {
  // ...
}
```

When a user finishes a quiz, I think the hook should be invoked from the following code of the Quiz module.

```
/**
 * Actions to take at the end of a quiz
 *
 * @param $quiz
 *  The quiz node
 * @param $rid
 *  Result id
 * @param $score
 *  Score as a number
 */
function quiz_end_actions($quiz, $score, $session_data) {
  // Call hook_quiz_finished().
  module_invoke_all('quiz_finished', $quiz, $score, $session_data);

  if (!empty($quiz->aid)) {
    actions_do($quiz->aid, $quiz, $score, $session_data);
  }

  return $score;
}
```

My hook is not invoked. What am I missing?

Comment: is your module called "wilson_random_task"? Are you sure that the `quiz_end_actions` function is being called?

Comment: I think in your 2nd code your function needs your module name. Ex:`function [module name]_quiz_end_actions($quiz, $score, $session_data)`

Comment: @NoSssweat That is a function of the Quiz module.

Comment: @2pha yes that is the name of my module. How can I be sure? I end the quiz so I expect it to be called. Are there any way to debug?

Comment: I usually use the devel module and it's dpm() function to quickly debug. Just temporarily add a dpm call inside the quiz_end_actions function to see if it's being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[2pha](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199925/drupal-7-hook-doesnt-execute#comment241607_199925) is correct: `quiz_end_actions()` is not necessarily called, contrary to what the code workflow could seem. In fact, [`quiz_take_quiz()`](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules%21contrib%21quiz%21quiz.module/function/quiz_take_quiz/mooc7) contains the following code.

```
// Remove session variables, save $rid
$session_data = $_SESSION['quiz_' . $quiz->nid];
unset($_SESSION['quiz_' . $quiz->nid]);
// NOTE: End actions might redirect the user somewhere. Code below this line might not get executed...
quiz_end_actions($quiz, $score, $session_data);
```

As the comment says, end actions could redirect the user to somewhere else, and the code after it would not be executed.